# Image File not found exception android

Tags: android, file, assets

Am trying to add icons to the grid dynamically based on the path provided by service,
i have added the icons inside the assets folder, am getting file not found exception, how can i fix it.

Below is my code,

```
            try
                 {
                InputStream im = context.getAssets().open(App.Path);
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(im, null);

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: try this `context.getResources().getAssets().open(App.Path);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is with prefix /assets/ :)

```
 try {
        String image = App.Path;

        if (image.contains("/assets/")) {
            image = image.replace("/assets/", "");
        }

        InputStream ims = getAssets().open(image);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have "Profile Registration.png" -> rename the file so it does not contain spaces. Something like: "profile_registration.png"

Comment: The image file is in the MenuIcons folder of the "assets" folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your files availablity.

If Files there,do following instructions

Instead of

```
InputStream im = context.getAssets().open(App.Path);
```

please use this

```
InputStreamReader im = new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("path name upto file")));
```

Please Use this.It will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 try {
        String image_path = App.Path;
        String filepath = null;
        if (image_path.contains("/ASSETS/")) {
             filepath = image_path .replace(ASSETS, "");
        }    
        InputStreamReader im = new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(filepath)));
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return;
    }
```